# Calculation on 3 weeks data in if statement

Tags: java

How to convert the integer to boolean? as i need to calculate the 3 weeks data in if statement but i encounter this error. Kindly advise Thanks you

```
    for (int i = 0; i < ShipmentForecast.size(); i++){
CalendarUtils.AddDaysToDate(getDate(ShipmentForecast.get(i).dateBucket), 21)),
            if (start == false){
            if (ShipmentForecast.get(i).dateBucket.compareTo(startDateCal) >= 0 ){

            }
                if (ShipmentForecast.size == 40){

                }
                DateTime date = DateTime.parse(
                        ShipmentForecast.get(i).dateBucket, 
                        DateTimeFormat.forPattern(SCPMFormatConstants.DATE_MCV))
                        .withTimeAtStartOfDay();

                if ( (date.equals(currentWeekStart)) || (date.isAfter(currentWeekStart)) )  {

                    start = true;
                }

            }
```

Comment: What are you trying to convert? Have you tried casting it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
 if (ShipmentForecast.size == 40){
```

to

```
if (ShipmentForecast.size() == 40){
```

Comment: Thanks you , Sorry that i not enough point to accept this answer. by the way thanks for your answer

Comment: I think you need to wait a while before you can upvote and accept.  Please wait a while